# Where in Europe is wild camping permitted?

Tags: camping, europe, access-rights

Is there any resource (website, book, etc) that lists all European countries, and the state of free camping?

Specifically, I want to see in which European countries I'm not fined when I place my tent somewhere outside of an official camping ground.

Comment: I don't know of such a list - what I do know however which may give you a head start is it's legal in Scotland, and in England the only such legal place is Dartmoor.

Comment: @berry120 - there are lots of open access areas in the UK - I've wild-camped in the Peaks and the Lakes. These areas are clearly marked on OS maps.

Comment: Open access does not mean that wild-camping is allowed.

Comment: This has also come up on the travel site http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/1340/1820

Comment: "Wild Camping" seems to have many meanings depending on country and activity. For some, it means parking your motorhome overnight by the side of a main road, but for many  others (myself included) it means wilderness camping in mountains, miles from the nearest road, house or other person. And sheep don't issue fines!

Comment: @Roddy - good point, another one to add to the FAQ.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but .. I've put up a tent next to the car besides country roads in a majority of the European countries, Turkey and Morocco without much problems at all. Out of 200+ nights doing so, we've been sent away 3 times. Once by the police, twice by hunters. Find a spot where few people pass by, wait for darkness to put up your tent.

Comment: In Portugal, it is forbidden to camp in the wild. A friend of mine was fined for a lot of money for camping in wilderness. Everyone else I know that do it, has to sneak and hide from the authorities. There is only one camp where you can camp in the wild in Portugal, its in the mountains, its called Covao da Ametade.

Comment: Here you can find a list of the wild camping laws of EVERY country in Europe. That should help :) [Wild camping laws of every European Country](http://momgoescamping.com/wild-camping-laws-europe/)

Answer (score 58):

After a bit of digging I found [this](http://www.guardian.co.uk/travel/2010/may/15/wild-camping-europe-uk-legalities), which covers some in Europe (not extensively as I first thought!)

It's worth pointing out that while for some (and probably most people here) wild camping means free-camping wandering around with a tent and supplies on foot, for many others it can mean driving around and parking up somewhere in a motor home. I refer to the first variety here, and this is the sort that is much less likely to give you problems (especially in countries where it's borderline.)

In any country, but especially those where it's more of a grey area, if you know where you're going beforehand then a quick call to the landowner (if any) to check that it's ok won't do you any harm. While it may not always be necessary, it may help to put your mind at rest so you're not worried about being approached or asked to leave during your stay.

Anyway, a general summary of countries in that link and elsewhere:

- **France** *(See above link)* A legal grey area, but is generally tolerated with the permission of landowners, or if you're well away from tourist sites. Don't light any fires.
- **England and Wales** *(See above link)* Generally not allowed without prior permission, though there are some exceptions (Dartmoor being the biggest one.)
- **Scotland** *(See above link)* Legal pretty much anywhere.
- **Ireland** It's tolerated in the more rural places, though it may be wise to obtain permission beforehand if you can.
- **Spain and Portugal** I believe it's tolerated but only in certain locations. Best to check with the landowner first to be sure.
- **Germany** Most of the links I can find suggest that it's not strictly speaking legal, but that many people have done it without any issues (providing you follow sensible precautions of course.)

  Note: German *wild zelten* [zelten = camping] does not mean wilderness camping. The *wild* here means illegal/without permission. With permission, camping is OK in many places and there are a few places where blanco permissions exist for particular situations.
  [More details in this other answer](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/25158/2404)
- **Netherlands** Generally not allowed. There are a few spots where it is allowed, near a designated pole for so called 'pole camping' ([paalkamperen](https://www.logerenbijdeboswachter.nl/paalkamperen)) '2020 note, the end of paalkamperen is announced, it is currently suspended due to COVID 19 but is said not to return.'
- **Italy** *(See above link)* It doesn't seem to be tolerated, in fact most sources I can find seem to say it's [explicitly banned in many places](http://www.go4awalk.com/ask/wildcampinginitaly.php). Having said that, the same link also says there's lots of good campsites in a lot of nice locations around, so that may be your alternative. (Edit: This may be a little harsher than reality, see Tullochgorum's comment below.)
- **Greece** *(See above link)* Illegal, but the rule is apparently rampantly ignored, with many unpoliced areas. The risk is on you if you try it here.
- **Norway** Legal pretty much anywhere. [Right to Roam](https://www.miljodirektoratet.no/globalassets/publikasjoner/M86/M86.pdf).
- **Sweden** Legal pretty much anywhere. [Outdoor Access Rights](http://www.swedishepa.se/Enjoying-nature/The-Right-of-Public-Access/Outdoor-Access-Rights-in-other-languages/).
- **Finland** Legal pretty much anywhere. [Everyman’s rights and the code of conduct on private land](http://hdl.handle.net/10138/159060).
- **Bulgaria** *(See above link)* An interesting one - I can't find any sources saying whether it's legal or not, but in the summer apparently hundreds of hippy families relocate to the beaches, wild camp there and often strip nude for good measure.
- **Estonia** *(See above link)* A legal grey area, widely tolerated but best to obtain permission from the land owner beforehand.
- **Albania** Legal here on public land, but sometimes restricted for environmental reasons. Check first.
- **Austria** Can't find any authoritative sources. General consensus is that it seems to be discouraged, but as long as you're sensible then there shouldn't be an issue.
- **Faroe Islands** [Not permitted](https://visitfaroeislands.com/plan-your-stay/accommodation/camping/). Camping is only permitted at designated campsites.

Comment: That looks great but unfortunately it covers only 6 countries out of approximately 45.

Comment: @roflcoptr Sorry, not quite sure what led me to believe that was extensive... still, I guess it's a start!

Comment: "hundreds of hippy families ... strip nude for good measure" blahahahaha. This is true, but not so widespread and not on the topic of "pitch my tent". In Bulgaria you can pitch your tent anywhere - except reserves. There are lots of fireplaces in the wilderness around cities and towns, also.

Comment: About Austria: it is generally "allowed". However, it is forbidden in the states Vienna and Tyrol as well as nature reserves.

Comment: To add, in Italy (at least around the Mt Blanc) it is forbidden below 2500m. Source: the guide in that cabin between the col and the Elisabetta refuge.

Comment: In Valle D'Aosta, Italy (one of the most beautiful mountain regions) it is explicitly allowed above 2500 metres amd between 8pm to 8am.

Comment: I was a bit sceptical about camping in dartmnoor being legal but [it turns out I was wrong](http://www.dartmoor.co.uk/where-to-stay/dartmoor-camping/wild-camping-on-dartmoor)

Comment: I've wild-camped quite extensively in the Italian Alps. So long as you are above the enclosed fields and away from woods (they are understandably very twitchy about fire), i never had any issues. Commonsense rules apply - pitch late, strike early, and keep away from busy beauty-spots. If you're pitching near a hut, it's polite to ask the guardian. I've never been turned down. The one time I got caught stealth-camping lower down the Ranger was very friendly and asked me politely to move on. But after a quick negotiation he relented and let me stay the night.

Comment: To add for the Netherlands: There is a very limited availablity see for completely free campsites see https://www.logerenbijdeboswachter.nl/vrij-kamperen and there are 'nature' campsites available for a small fee https://www.logerenbijdeboswachter.nl/natuurkampeerterreinen

Comment: @Liam - I live on the edge of Dartmoor and the legal situation is a bit more complicated. Camping is allowed, but not everywhere. There is a definitive map here: http://www.dartmoor.gov.uk/visiting/vi-enjoyingdartmoor/camping/camping-map (drill down for details). In practice the application of the rules is quite liberal. If you use common-sense and practice Leave No Trace you won't run into any trouble. Just don't camp on the path up to Hound Tor...

Comment: In France it's very much tolerated around the refuges that you will find in the alps/ national parks

Comment: In Spain it is not allowed to place your tent anywhere. There are very few exceptions such as in high altitude as long as it's not a national park or something like that, point is, these exceptions don't apply very often.

Comment: Does all this refer to a one-night sleep somewhere in the open (especially if you are on a road trip in the middle of nowhere the chances of not finding shelter before nightfall are pretty big) or remaining for several days and nights at the same location? Because unpacking your tent, sleeping 6-7 hours, then packing it up again and leaving is quite different compared to building up a camp for several days.

Comment: Austria: not legal <br />
Croatia: not legal <br />
Slovenia: not legal <br />
Hungaria: not  legal <br />
Italy: not legal <br />
Germany: not legal <br />
I am an austrian, and have slept in hammocks in all the countries above. Only was sent away once in croatia by police with a warning. But i sleep stealthy

Comment: @berry120: Hope you don't mind. I added some info and a link to a detailed answer about Germany. I think this info it is better found in your answer than in another answer.

Comment: Dartmoor exception is gone now, it seems

Answer (score 22):

It's allowed in Sweden. It's called Allemansrätten.

Comment: The same law applies in Norway

Comment: The same law also exists in Finland (jokamiehenoikeus). Translated literally to English it is "every man's rights".

Answer (score 20):

Generally in England and Wales it is illegal to wild camp anywhere without prior permission from the land owner. Although some UK national parks are more tolerant than others!! In my experience certainly in the English and Welsh national parks it is tolerated as long as you are not seen and you leave no trace including not starting any fires.

For more information check out the national parks website: http://www.nationalparks.gov.uk/visiting/camping.htm

As @StephenPaulger says it is different in Scotland (thankfully) under certain conditions. Please check this link out:

http://www.outdooraccess-scotland.com/out-and-about/recreation-activities/wild-camping/

Being on holiday in France, some places get very iffy about wild camping!! So as in the UK its probably best to check with the land owner first.

Comment: Your information regarding England & Wales is misleading. It has nothing to do with the tolerance of the National Parks as they don't own much land at all. The land they do own will be car parks, buildings etc. All land in the England and Wales is owned by somebody. Technically, you must seek permission from the landowner to camp. It is unlikely that the landowner would be the National Park.

Comment: Just to add my experience to what Aim Kai and @Jim are saying here. Much of Snowdonia and the Lake district are owned by a combination of either hill farmers or the National trust. **But** the National Park authority manages much of the land (footpaths, etc.) the farmer may or may not conduct work on behalf of the park authority so ownership is complicated in National Parks. Enclosed spaces will generally be exlusivly owned by a single party. Higher on the hill and in moorland several parties will have a say on access, etc. and **one** of these will be the National Park Authourity

Comment: @Liam The question about permission to wild camp. The issue of enclosed space is irrelevant. National Parks maintain many footpaths, as do the National Trust (not relevant to the OP). If you choose to follow the letter of the law then permission to camp must be sought from the landowner. This may be a farmer, or a body such as the National Trust - but it will almost always never be the National Park, as they own very little land per se. Within the Lake District NP the biggest landowner is the National Trust. In that case permission from the National Trust or tenant farmer would be sought.

Answer (score 19):

This is a pure theory, if you're asking about permission... you have to understand that the rules and laws are set up for people that park 3 cars, make 5 big tents, lot of noise and leave a lot of rubbish. Practically, when you are a good outdoor person, quiet and never leave any rubbish behind you, and you need just sleep for one night somewhere with just a sleeping bag or maybe small tent when it rains / it's cold, then I think this is not a real "camping" and it's not a problem almost anywhere. I'm normally doing this without any problems even in countries like Austria (once we slept under the sign "Kampieren verboten" which translates to "Camping prohibited" in english :-))

So, just don't provoke the land owners too much, build your tent somewhere hidden and after it gets dark, and leave the place soon in the morning. The less people know about you, the better, also for your safety. Sometimes the land owners notice you and are very friendly, especially in countries like Spain and even in Austria :) I didn't have any problems after years of this practice.

Don't sleep this way in big cities, it's dangerous. You may get robbed. The more abandoned / outdoor site it is, the safer for you.

Answer (score 16):

In Scotland, it is allowed, with conditions.

[Wild camping in Scotland](http://walking.visitscotland.com/usefulinfo/wild-camping)

One restriction that I know of is that [camping is not allowed on the eastern shore of Loch Lomond](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-scotland-tayside-central-12698722). There are likely to be restrictions during the hunting season as well, there are phone lines where you can find out about hunting activities.

Comment: Can you expand your answer?  Include some conditions and maybe a link to more information?

Comment: @studiohack -  the answer pretty much covers it - Scotland has some of the most liberal land-access rights in the world. You can basically camp on any unenclosed land unless it's temporarily closed for stalking during August-October. There's a stalking hotline here: http://www.outdooraccess-scotland.com/Practical-guide/Public/heading-for-the-scottish-hills. Apart from that, you're simply expected to  follow the Leave No Trace rules so as not to spoil the experience for others.

Comment: I would have suggested a link to HillPhones for the last sentence, but that appears to be hidden behind an obnoxious "*We won't let you read this unless you run our scripts*" message.  `:-(`

Answer (score 14):

In Latvia, Lithuania, Estonia, Poland You can camp almost anywhere in forest and near public waters. Latvia is forest country, and You can camp almost anywhere. There are no restrictions. If the land owner doesn't want to allow it, he must place a sign. There are restrictions on national parks only. In national parks it's allowed in specific places only, but it's free anyway.
It's similar in Estonia. You can camp almost anywhere except for nature reserves. If a landowner doesn't want you they must place a sign saying so. Try to avoid places near to houses.

Comment: Hi ugis and welcome to The Great Outdoors! Thank you for adding your helpful answer. If you want to improve it, it would be great to include some sources.

Comment: @ugis: I have suggested a few edits that according to me would improve the answer.

Answer (score 14):

It is generally illegal in Denmark. You may sleep on all beaches, but you are not allowed to pitch a tent on beaches. In some state-forrests you may camp where you like.

More than 1.000 primitive campsites are scattered around the country. Most are free - some cost 1-3 euro pr. night. They may just be a lawn but some have shelters, firewood and access to water and toilet. These campsites are only for walking and biking users, so if you travel by car or motorcycle, you may not use them.

You can see the locations of camping-sites and forrests here: http://udinaturen.dk/?searchid=7653dbbf-b087-4c30-9edc-2517a02fd28e

Answer (score 13):

Some extra info about **France**.

In general, wild camping is forbidden in France, *except when stated otherwise*. As any other country, France has a number of regional and national natural parks, where "bivouac" (setting up your tent after 7pm and packing it back before 8am) might be allowed. Regulations are specific to each park, and you should get to know it before you enter it and plan to camp there.

A park's regulation can also depend on factors:

- time of the year. eg., some parks only allow it during the summer.
- location *within the park*. Some parks allow wild camping in general, but not in certain locations due to specific reasons (high natural hazards, water contamination risks, etc.). The areas where wild camping is specifically forbidden are marked by signs on the side of paths accessing said areas. Those signs most likely will only be written in French. In a way, these are "exceptions within exceptions", since camping in natural parks are already an exception within the French law.
- temporary risk (eg, if a huge wildfire is going on).

I have never seen natural parks allowing campfires, or leaving your tent up at the same location at daytime. Might exist but I seriously doubt it. Don't be an idiot and light campfires in the wilderness; bring a stove and a gas can.

If you scroll down a bit on [this web page](https://www.lecampingsauvage.fr/legislation-et-reglementation/camping-sauvage-bivouac), you will find **a map of France with all said parks and their current regulation**. I am sorry, everything is in French. If some things are still cryptic through Google translate, feel free to ask me.

Worth noting that like other European countries, France also has a number of **free, non-guarded shelters**, mostly in mountainous areas. Most of these shelters consist of a small room with a stove for heating, and a second "floor" right below the roof where you can sleep. These shelters are quite rustic, and are mostly maintained on a volunteer basis, by local people, or alpine clubs, for example. You can expect to find wood there for using with the stove. Common practice is bringing back into the shelter as much wood as you have used, obviously. Such shelters are marked with a "empty red house" pictograph on IGN maps (those are the reference maps in France). On [this website](http://www.refuges.info/), you can find more or less updated infos about most shelters, like, if it has been vandalized, water access, a stove, wood, etc. Once again, it's all in French.

As most people already have said, if you are discrete enough, you probably will not get caught even when camping in illegal areas. However, the author's question specifically asked about where it was legal. Obviously, camping on private land is OK if you have the owner's approval.

One last anecdote: during my teenage years, I went hiking for several days in Corsica, where wild camping is strictly forbidden. Putting up your tent close to guarded shelters was allowed, as long as you paid something like 5€/night/person. At the end of the trip, we were all lacking money, and could not pay this fee (yes, we were pretty stupid back then). We ended up playing it fair and going to the guards saying we could not afford it. All of them were OK with that, as long as we stayed close to the shelters. They insisted on warning us that if we were to be found wild camping in forbidden areas, they would fine us hard. They actually did that to another group of people. Moral of the story: just **play it fair** and remember that the guards' main concern is the protection of the park.

Answer (score 9):

I can only answer for Switzerland.
It's legal to "wildcamp" and most ground belongs to Farmers which can be asked anytime, and most of them will let you pitch your tent.

For more information see the following links (in German/French):

[Campieren & Biwakieren](http://www.sac-cas.ch/umwelt/naturvertraeglicher-bergsport/campieren-biwakieren.html)

[Biwakieren Verbotsliste](http://www.alternatives-wandern.ch/biwak/biwakverbote.htm)

Comment: This is not correct. Wild camping is generally *legal* ins Switzerland, *but* many cantons and municipalities have special regulations. Some even prohibit wild camping outright. A source to start is http://www.alternatives-wandern.ch/biwak/biwakverbote.htm (in German though).

Comment: @fgysin, thanks for the clarification! I thought biwakieren is mereley an emergency measure http://www.sac-cas.ch/umwelt/naturvertraeglicher-bergsport/campieren-biwakieren.html

Answer (score 9):

It's legal to camp almost everywhere in the Czech and Slovak Republics except national parks. You are not allowed to make a campfire closer than 50 m from the forest. Although there is a small risk of being fined.

Answer (score 9):

Romania: I have some experiences here, and I can say that wild camping is permitted, unless it is someone's land surrounded by a fence, however loose or abandoned it may seem (although in Romania you can never know who owns which patch of land, but mostly it is safe and fine). There are plenty of good places for wild camping, especially if you get a bit away from the main tourist tracks, which tend to have some trash here and there, as a result of the irresponsible city people.

Comment: Hi Akabelle and welcome to The Great Outdoors! Thanks for your helpful answer - you could improve it by adding some official sources to it, if available.

Comment: Sorry, @Paul , unfortunately I couldn't find any official sources so far, although I've been looking. Camping is not really regulated in Romania, just in a few places where it is certainly forbidden (for example by the administration of a given national park). Here camping is still somewhat instinctual, not fully regulated.

Answer (score 9):

There's quite a good guide I've found on wild camping in the UK here: [Wild Camping.](http://www.campsites.co.uk/guides/wild-camping)

In general, there's more acceptance than you'd expect from simply reading the laws, if you show respect.

- In Scotland, the law is different to the rest of the UK. Generally you're allowed to camp on the majority of unenclosed land if you follow a (sensible) code of conduct. There are some exceptions around Loch Lomond and the Trossachs.
- In England and Wales, with the exception of Dartmoor, the law says there's no right without the owner's permission.
- In practice, so long as you follow the wild camping code and behave, you will often be OK. But you do need to move on if asked.
- High up in the Lakes and Snowdonia, you should be fine.
- The Peak District and Yorkshire Dales and Moors are not so easy, because of the fire risk on dry moorland.
- Bivvying is tolerated on Exmoor, for single night stops.
- Two locations are officially allowed in the Brecon Beacons - Mellte and Llech Llia.

Answer (score 9):

Additional for **Greece**:

I'm a wild camper for many years in Greece. I have never any issue with locals or police.. Ok, I am careful in general but I guess also lucky. :) Yes, it is illegal and you must know where to go. The best is to ask the locals, or other campers that you will find there. As a general rule, after sunset you wont have any issue putting the tent. If you have are not sure about the place and have a relatively small tent then the safest is to just flatten it by day. Nobody is going to give you a fine for having a picnic.. Also is a little difficult to give you a fine if you are in the beach, or just somewhere away from the tent.. All these of course vary from place to place.

I will list a few places that come in mind bellow:

Samothraki: Extremely beautiful island. You can easily camp in the forest and near the natural bathtubs and waterfalls. Also there is a government "wild living "campsite" that is nice and really cheap.

Other islands:
Skopelos, Limnos (unfortunately is not that green), Lesvos: highly recommended for camp in different place every night. There are so much to see in this pretty big island. Crete is also highly recommended.

Halkidiki: Its mainland and its separated in 3 peninsulas. Forger about the southern (1st as we say) as is the most touristic and mainly full or hotels, clubs and nightlife.
The middle peninsula has places like, Kavourotrypes (too many people the last years unfortunately), Kriaritsi, Kalamitsi. If you are driving on this route you can also find countless quiet and nice places to camp.
The northern peninsula is more wild but not less beautiful. Around Olympiada and further towards the edge of the peninsula there are many beaches. I would also recommend to take the mountain road above Olympiada. The forest is vast, wildly beautiful and full or natural fountains.

I think that as long as you are away from villages and the road, respect the people around as well as the nature you'll be fine in many places and islands.

Answer (score 7):

*Don't* even think about wild camping in Italy. In most cities it is illegal, and more important it is highly dangerous. Depending on the area, you may be mugged, raped, stabbed, or flash flooded by a torrent of mud.

Comment: that doesn't really covers with my experience. do you have any references?

Comment: @Roflcoptr: The reference is that I know my country. Most communes forbid wild camping because they want to have a legal reason to prevent unregulated gypsies camping and/or more in general Camping Cars (which are a huge pain for cities). When it comes to dangers, it is not uncommon to hear of people wild camping that are assaulted and robbed. Flash floods may occur in some areas, especially in the North. We had people die (mostly boy scouts) a few years ago, in a place where I camped myself (like an idiot). It's difficult for me to find references to news happened years ago, but that's it.

Comment: *"don't wild camp in Italy. In most cities it is illegal"*, on earth, who would ever camp in cities? We speak about outdoor.

Comment: @Tomas: cities includes all the territory of the commune, which extends also to the countryside.

Comment: @StefanoBorini, OK. In English, AFAIK, city does mean only the city itself, so one should probably use *commune* or *municipality*. Probably question for [English Language and Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/) :-)

Comment: @Tomas: the city has borders, but the laws of the city apply to the whole territory of the commune. In some cases, we also have "province", which I think they are called "counties" in English. Then regions (20 in total). Most of these laws against camping are city laws. I don't know if there are state and regional levels laws about camping, but I do know the ones in my city and nearby ones, and it's absolutely forbidden. It's also quite prominent, since it's clearly stated at the entrance of the city borders.

Comment: You can also get mugged/raped/killed walking to your hotel. I've wild camped with a tent throughout Italy, often even not that far from roads or towns, without any remark. I'd consider the risks limited and the same as the rest of Europe.

Comment: I've wild-camped extensively in the Italian Alps. Just be considerate and use your common sense. Never had a bad experience, and everyone has gone out of their way to be friendly.

Comment: *I wouldn't take this answer seriously.* It is probably written by someone who has never wild camped and is too terrified of things. I've met similar people in Spain, when I asked them directions they said "But you want to walk?? It's 10 kilometers!" Many people are too terified of adventures like this even in their own backyard so any "advice" like this must be taken with a pinch of salt :-)

Comment: @Tomas or maybe he is someone who knows Italy because he lived there more than 20 years?

Answer (score 7):

In Serbia it is legal and everywhere is free.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is also called "Freedom to roam". Here is a list of countries with detailed information of what is allowed and not allowed around Europe: [Freedom to roam.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_to_roam)

Comment: It's not the same thing unfortunately - freedom to roam doesn't necessarily imply freedom to wild camp. In the UK for instance freedom to roam applies over most countryside, but there are very few areas where wild camping is allowed.

Answer (score 6):

Camping by small van or large estate car mpv, overnight without problems in Spain, beach parking areas and beach, especially Castel de Ferro area, Almeria coast line, you come across a few camper vans and also local rod fishermen night fishing forming tents with umbrellas and the like.

France - Parked all over BUT discreet! Places in villages as in center parking, back lane, or grassed parking areas, some have designated areas in small towns, there's also lay-byes that are well off road in places, on the main route's lay-byes are used by many and some have toilets, I am always aware to park either where others are or completely out of vision for safety, I have only been moved once, there was a big boules tournament following day, I should have noticed adverts, so always check!!! Could end up in middle of a car boot sale in morning, thats been done!

So really just use common-sense and respect.

Answer (score 6):

In **Greece** wild camping is illegal in general. The more famous/well known is the place where you camp, the more probable is to have a visit from the police. Checks more often take place during summer in islands and in general near tourist sites. On the other hand there are certain places where wild camping is silently permitted since it is a boost to their economy and other places that it is encouraged (eg Tilos) but these are the exceptions to the rule. 
Camping is also not allowed in mountains but you will not find much trouble there, specially if you decide to camp near a refuge. Of course you are not allowed to make any campfire in the forest and specially in national parks.

Answer (score 6):

Switzerland again:

all farmland and forest area is owned by someone who has to give you permission.

However, I never bother, but I apply strictly no/low impact techniques: Cooking only in designated recreational areas, and not where I will camp and sleep; camp and sleep in a "stealth camp", sneaking in when night falls, disappearing in the morning before anyone notices you are there.
Above the alpine grasslands, and even in the grasslands if there is not yet or no more stock present, bivouacking is accepted if you leave no trace (trash!)

A lager group or a longer stay should always go for the landowners prior consent.

Answer (score 5):

I've wild camped in Italy around Lake Como, Sardinia, Norway, all over the UK and all over France including bang outside Nice airport in the central reservation of the dual carriageway. Never had one problem in 15 years.

Like everyone has said be discreet. Camp late, leave early, noise to a minimum, no fires. Basically tuck yourself away out of site and you'll be fine.

After all, if someone is wandering around in a remote spot, in the middle of the night they are either lost or a nutter! And they'll think the same of you.

Comment: Those walking around in a remote spot in the night aren't just lost or nuts.  The only time I've encountered such people while wild camping, they were poachers.

Answer (score 4):

**Croatia:**
Generally, it's prohibited anywhere to camp (strictly prohibited in national parks). Not even if landowner gives you a permission. Camping is allowed only in camps that have permission for that business.

However, law says that local authorities can allow camping in some areas during specific events.

If you plan to do wild camping in Croatia outside of tourist regions, as long as you don't do any damage to your surroundings, they will NEVER try to fine you. In most cases they will even ask if you need any help...

Answer (score 2):

**Italy**

Wild camping in Italy is actually not directly [regulated](https://fringeintravel.com/legge-sul-campeggio-libero-in-italia-regolamenti-normative-e-divieti/) (the link is only in Italian, sorry). In general, if camping is not forbidden, then it is legal; laws concerning camping are usually deliberated by local government (e.g. region, country, town). I remember vaguely, from my studies of private law, that the civil code (and thus an ensemble of national laws) that it is possible also to camp in farm fields--if you do not damage the crop, and even without authorization from the field owner, but at the moment I do not remember the reference law that applies to this case.

Answer (score 0):

In **Slovenia** it is technically not legal, but in reality it depends where you pitch it.

If you pitch tent near populated areas, private land and stay more time than just sleep till morning you can get fined.

In case you are hiking in the hills or mountains it is not so strict. As long as you camp off the trail in forest and leave no trace policy, leave early in the morning, nobody will fine you. I did it a lot and had a great time. The exception is national park, where fines are higher and regime is stricter.

In Italian remote hills or mountains I had no problems and the fines are probably low as I know it. In Austria the fines are very high so I wouldn't dare to pitch it even in hills or mountains. I can't say how things are precisely, because I am not from Austria.

Answer (score -2):

In some countries, they do not allow tents, but camping is technically legal if you do not use a tent, except national parks and other protected areas where you can not enter during the night. In summer months rules are more strict, for fire protection reasons,so they can stop you, just for being outdoors, anytime, even during the day. Of course if you camp somewhere, even with no tent, if it is private land, they may charge you with trespassing.

In some European countries, things are more easy, like there is more public land, benches, wooden tables etc. Other places you see everywhere fences and signs and it is quite sad.
I do not use tent, and use a tarp only when it is raining. On raining use of tent applies to act of extreme weather,or unpredictable events so no problem on tents, there.
Camping on mountains, tent law is of little concern, you concern more about wild animals, hunters is some places, food resources etc.
Camping law apply to protect the environment and improper use of public resources, and it can be fair sometimes.

Tents offer no protection, except maybe for the wind, but there is almost always a wind protected spot. Tents also do not offer good view and sense of surrounding, and in low temperatures get full of mist. Tents are heavy, bulky. Even if I carry one, I rarely use, so I have to retire mine.

Comment: "Some countries" isn't very specific - certainly not useful to someone wanting to know _where_ they can stop overnight.

Comment: There are limitations to national parks, forests sometimes even during the day. Sometime people think it is allowed because they are at places impossible to check or they get help from locals. In rare cases, locals also might also call on authorities if they feel like, usually from excessive noise, excessive garbage, long time camping same place, trespassing their land etc.  The only safe way to know is to ask for local regulations. Sometimes same country has different set of rules based on area or situation. So research first.