# Where in Europe is it legal to hunt small game without a licence?

Tags: survival, hunting, europe

As I'd like to do some survival in Europe, one way to gather food is hunting.

In which Europese countries is it legal to hunt small game like rabbits and ducks, without or with an easy to obtain licence?

The best answer would be comparable to this one: [Where in Europe is wild camping permitted?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/111/14665)

Comment: I don't have any knowledge myself to start this off, but I believe the best way of answering this is by one community wiki. Otherwise I can see this becoming a long list of answers each with some additional info about one specific region.

Comment: This is almost impossible to answer not just because it's going to vary between countries, but it will additionally vary for different kinds of animals, and methods of hunting - Snares? Hunting dog? Falconry? Please tell me you don't expect to be able to use a gun.

Comment: As imsodin mentioned, a community wiki would be the best option, since it does indeed vary per country. If people could provide a short summary of the options (wildlife + methods) in that country and a link to a page that tells more, that would already be very helpful.

Comment: I am voting to close as too broad.  You could write a book and not have a complete answer to this question.

Comment: But isn't it just as broad as the linked question?

Comment: @JamesJenkins Would you prefer 44 questions, one for each country in Europe?